# Manim. Бесконечно убывающая геометричская прогрессия на примере квадарата

Tags: python, математика, анимация

Всех приветствую! Ищу подсказку как сделать бесконечно убывающую геометрическую прогрессию на основе квадрата в библиотеке [Manim](https://www.manim.community/).

Ожидаемый результат:
[image]

То что я получил:
[image: То что у меня получилось])

Возможно я пошел не по тому пути, по слишком сложному. Мне сложно вставлять квадраты, они слишком маленькие получаются, невозможно их поставить на свое место. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно все оформить?

```python
from manim import *

class MyScene(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        square = Square()
        self.play(Create(square))
        one_moment = MathTex("1").move_to(square)
        self.wait()
        self.play(Write(one_moment))
        self.wait(2)
        self.play(FadeOut(one_moment))
        rectangle2 = Rectangle().scale(0.5).move_to(square, DOWN)
        self.play(Create(rectangle2))
        mathtex = MathTex("\\frac{1}{2}").move_to(rectangle2).scale(0.5)
        self.play(Write(mathtex))
        rectangle3 = Rectangle(width=1, height=1)
        rectangle3.move_to([0.5, 0.5, 0])
        self.play(Create(rectangle3))
        mathtex_2 = MathTex("\\frac{1}{4}").move_to(rectangle3).scale(0.5)
        self.play(Write(mathtex_2))
        self.wait(5)
        rectangle4 = Rectangle(width=0.5, height=0.5)
        rectangle4.move_to([0.75, -1, 0])
        self.play(Create(rectangle4))
scene = MyScene()
scene.render()
```